# Cannot start any Tabris 1.0 application on iOS

Tags: ios, tabris

*Sorry, but I wasn't sure whether to post Tabris questions here or on GitHub, now that 1.0 is available?  This is a dup of one I just raised on GitHub...*

I've had Tabris 1.0 for a few days now, running ok on browser and Android, but I cannot get the iOS client to start at all. Here is my error in XCode, which is the same whether it is an emulated device or a real iPad:

2013-04-24 09:45:53.616 RapHello[2636:907] *** 17 DAY(S) OF TABRIS TRIAL LEFT** 
2013-04-24 09:45:53.620 RapHello[2636:907] -[AppDelegate clientDidBecomeReady]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e51fb70
2013-04-24 09:45:53.621 RapHello[2636:907]  **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate clientDidBecomeReady]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e51fb70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x343ae3e7 0x3c238963 0x343b1f31 0x343b0737 0x34308208 0x342ff349 0x34c16b7f 0x361c3d11 0x36215b7d 0x361bdd1f 0x361bd7ad 0x361bd1ef 0x37eb15f7 0x37eb1227 0x343833e7 0x3438338b 0x3438220f 0x342f523d 0x342f50c9 0x3621446d 0x362112b9 0xb7981 0xb7908)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

This happens quite early on. I see the TABRIS logo screen on the device, but then this crash and nothing else happens.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong - obviously something quite basic.

Thanks, John

Comment: I guess GitHub is the place then!

Answer (score 0):

To fix that problem you need to add the following method to your AppDelegate.m :

```
- (void)clientDidBecomeReady {
   /*
    Called when the Tabris client did become ready and will start a new session. 
    */
}
```

We will fix this in our trial download asap.